UK: Do I need SAPS calculation when changing glazing?
I am having my windows changed as part of a wider house renovation.  The house has an existing extension which is approx 20 years old.  The single-storey extension added roughly 1.5m across the rear of the house.
I am having the wall removed between two rooms which benefitted from the increased floor area when the extension was added.  The two rooms currently have sliding patio doors, and I want to replace them with a single large sliding door when the two rooms become a single large room.
My architect is saying I need a SAPS calculation because of the increased area of glazing.  But I can't find any source that says SAPS calculations are needed when the floor area is not being changed.

I would expect an architect to be a lot more familiar with the local rules on this than a homeowner. Disambiguation here: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/standard-assessment-procedure

I am not an expert in these regs, but here is what looks to be a useful summary.
The change in the glazing could affect the energy performance rating of the house, which would invalidate its current EPC. Without an up-to-date EPC, you can't legally rent or sell the house. If you are not planning to rent or sell, then you do not need to have the SAP calculation and EPC re-done, but if you are planning to rent or sell, then you will need the new calculation, as I would imagine that using an EPC that you know to be out of date will amount to fraud.
I would guess that enlarging the window/doors comes under "extending the fixed services for mechanical ventilation".

Would you expect roughly £600 to be a reasonable fee for a SAP calculation?

Cost discussions are off topic here. Please see the [help].

Contact several companies that do the SAP calculations and ask for pricing, @PaulSuart. Only way to know what's reasonable for your area.
